# Has it ever been suggested that Natasha Romanoff is of the Romanoff Dynasty?

Tags: marvel, black-widow

For reference, the [House of Romanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Romanov)

> (also transcribed Romanoff; Russian: Рома́новы, tr. Románovy, IPA: [rɐˈmanəvɨ]) was the reigning imperial house of Russia from 1613 to 1917. They achieved prominence after the Tsarina, Anastasia Romanova, was married to the First Tsar of Russia, Ivan the Terrible.

Has there ever been a plotline where Natasha was implied to be a lost Romanov, or is it just a matter of someone picking an obviously Russian name ?

Comment: Romanov or Romanoff means son or descendant of someone with the personal name of Roman.  The royal Romanoffs, and many other noble families, are descended from Andre Kobyla c.  1347.  The royal Romanovs are the branch descended from Roman Yurievich Zakharyin-Yuriev c. 1500, and probably many other men named Roman had descendants using the surname Romanov in many Romanov families. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Romanov  And also see this quesition and answers: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/57223/did-the-third-rome-theory-help-make-michael-romanov-tsar

Comment: Romanon, Romanoff.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly *implied* on a number of occasions, but **not explicitly confirmed**.

In [*Black Widow: Origins #1*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Widow:_Deadly_Origin_Vol_1_1), we have this panel.

[image]

But then closely followed by someone (quite understandably) pointing out that this is a common name in Russia.

[image]

Note also that her official biography on Marvel.com does stress that it's never been conclusively demonstrated.

> Although her exact parentage is unknown, it is rumored that she is
> related to the late Romanov dynasty—the former rulers of Russia—but
> those claims have so far been unproven. Orphaned as a child, she was
> rescued during an attack on Stalingrad by a man named Ivan Petrovitch
> Bezukhov, who looked after and trained the girl.
>
> <sub><sup>[NATASHA ROMANOVA: The Black Widow](https://www.marvel.com/characters/black-widow-natasha-romanova/in-comics)</sup></sub>